# Python 3.4 Tkinter - How can I just delete a string anywhere in a text widget?

Tags: python-3.x, textbox, tkinter

If you need more details, I'm happy to provide, but instead let me just provide the scenario.

I've done this to insert HTML line breaks into my text:

```
count = int(text_entry.index('end-1c').split('.')[0])
for i in range(count):
    if i != 0.0:
        text_entry.insert('%d.end' % i, '<br>')
```

Put simply, I just want to undo this after the rest of my function executes, returning the text to its original state. I tried using **`text.delete()`** and **`text.replace()`**, but I couldn't seem to simply remove the inserted string without altering the rest of the text. I'm new to Tkinter, so I'm sure I'm not understanding the use of the indices or something basic.

I appreciate your time and attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text widget has a [delete](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.delete-method) method which will delete any range of text that you want. It does exactly what it should -- give it two character positions and it will delete the text between them.

For example to delete the entire second line of text you can do:

```
text_entry.delete("2.0", "3.0")
```

If you're trying to remember ranges of text so that you can delete them later, make sure you delete from the bottom up. If you delete from the top down, the first delete will cause all of the other saved indexes to be incorrect. If you want to delete lines 2 and 4, when you delete line 2, line 4 becomes line 3, etc. If you delete line 4 first, the line numbers of all previous lines remain unaffected.

If you're simply wanting to undo a series of actions, you can programmatically call the [edit_undo](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.edit_undo-method) method. Since the undo mechanism is a bit under-documented for Tkinter, I'll include an example. The key points are:

1. set `undo=True` in the text widget
2. call `edit_separator()` before adding your text
3. call `edit_undo()`, which will undo everything up to the moment of the last separator

That last point is important -- if you let the user enter other data, separators get automatically added. This trick works best if there's no interaction between the time you insert a bunch of data and then undo those inserts.

Here's a working example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.toolbar = tk.Frame(self)
        self.toolbar.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        do_button = tk.Button(self.toolbar, text="do it", command=self.do_it)
        undo_button = tk.Button(self.toolbar, text="UNdo it", command=self.undo_it)
        do_button.pack(side="left")
        undo_button.pack(side="left")

        self.text = tk.Text(self, wrap="word", undo=True)
        self.text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        with open(__file__, "r") as f:
            self.text.insert("1.0", f.read())

    def do_it(self):
        self.text.edit_separator()
        count = int(self.text.index('end-1c').split('.')[0])
        for i in range(1, count):
            self.text.insert('%d.end' % i, '<br>')
            text = self.text.get("1.0", "end-1c")

    def undo_it(self):
        self.text.edit_undo()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Oh, wow. That's very helpful, thank you. I think the undo option is exactly what I need. I kind of understood the text.delete() option, but I think it just wasn't going to work for me, because the text entry was less than predictable, but I just want to reverse my own actions, so this makes more sense for my needs.  I'll experiment with the delete() option again for my own education too, though. Thank you for your time on this.

Comment: What do you mean by "the text entry was less than predictable"? It's a very solid API that works exactly as documented. What did you find unpredictable about it?

Comment: No, I meant what is entered by the user isn't of static length or form, so it made deleting by indices more challenging. The undo method works better for what I'm doing, since I'm just looking to reverse my own post-edits.